# Relational Ado Without Primary Foreign Key Relation in yii

Tags: activerecord, yii

I have 2 tables. one is groups and other is frames.
groups has id, name, owner as columns.
grouppage has id,name and user_id.
users can have group pages. users can edit page if they are owner of the group .Means user_id = owner. Otherwise users can not edit the group page.
Hence i have a public property called can_edit.this is true if user_id = owner.
now i want to connect these 2 table using relational ADO. But how do i do it? because i have to connect the user_id in grouppage table to owner in groups. Neither owner nor group_id are primary keys?

Any solution /ideas

Thanks to all
Smith

Comment: Why do "users have group pages"? Wouldn't it be more reasonable to set `group_id` in `grouppage` (and maybe leave `user_id` there too if you need it)? Anyway, your tables' schemes could help in understanding of your problem.